# mongoDB, express, webpack-dev-middleware, console.log db collection won't work

Tags: mongodb, express, webpack

I try to setting up together mongoDB, express and webpack-dev-middleware. I want to do it the simplest way as it's possible, using as little adding modules as it's possible. I'm basing on several tutorials (I haven't found one simply). Everything worked to moment when I tred console log collection from mongoDB. I have nothing print in my consola.

I'm sure that connection to mongoDB is ok. I think it's something with webpac-dev-middleware and routing, but I can't find some helpfull information or tutorial.

server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');

const app = express(); 

const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var db;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/testit' (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Connection error: ',err);
  db = database;
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('MongoDB listening on 3000');
 });
});

const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
      stats: {
        colors: true,
      }
  });
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
     log: console.log
});

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware);
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    db.collection('quotes').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
      console.log(results);  //according to tutorial this line should to display console log, but I have nothing, even if I try console log error. Or whatever...
    });
});

app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  db.collection('quotes').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    console.log('saved to database');
    res.redirect('/');
  }); 
});

var listener = app.listen(8888, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + listener.address().port + ' mode: ' + 
app.settings.env);
});
```

webpack.confing.js

```
'use strict';

var Webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var config = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        './public/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
        },
    devServer: {
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, x-id, Content-Length, X-Requested-With",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
        },
        inline: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015','react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new Webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Please, help me find where exactly problem is. I'm sure I missunderstand something, but I don't know what.

Comment: You should not post actual working credentials in your question. I've edited them out, but please go change your password. Regarding your question: do you have a file called `index.html` in the root directory of your project?

Comment: Thank you very much. Normally I remeber about corvering about users and passwords. And yes, index.html is in root directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `express.static` will find the `index.html` file and serve it, and the request for `/` will therefore never reach your route handler.

If you want it to get called, you need to declare it before `express.static`:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    db.collection('quotes').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
      console.log(results);
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); // respond with the `index.html` file
    });
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, if someone want to use it, this part of code should looks like:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) =>{
    db.collection('quotes').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
      console.log(results);
    });
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

Add ***next***.